# Chrome Extension: How to reload tab from anywhere using keyboard events?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I am having issues with getting access to the Chrome's tab ID. I can fetch it, but it remains *inside* the extension and I cannot use it *outside* the extension, despite the fact that I was able to record keyboard events *outside* the extension.

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**

1. User navigates to a tab and fetches the tabId with a 'capture' button
2. The tabId is stored as a global variable
3. User then can navigate to any other tab inside his browser and from there with a key combination the user can reload the captured tab at any given moment by pressing CTRL + SHIFT simultaneously

**extension.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Extension</title>
  <style>
  body {
    min-width: 357px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  </style>
    <p>Step 1. Navigate to tab you want to refresh and click the 'capture' button</p>
    <button type="button" id="capture">Capture!</button>
    <p id="page"></p>
    <p>Step 2. Now you can reload that tab from anywhere by pressing CTRL+SHIFT simultaneously</p>
  </div>

  <script src="contentscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Extension",
  "description": "This extension allows you to trigger page refresh on key combinations from anywhere",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "extension.html"
  },
   "web_accessible_resources": ["script.js"],
   "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
}
```

**contentscript.js**

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("script.js");
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
```

**script.js**

```
'use strict';

var isCtrl = false;
var tabId = 0;

document.onkeyup=function(e){
    if(e.which === 17) {
        isCtrl=false;
    }
};

document.onkeydown=function(e){
    if(e.which === 17) {
        isCtrl=true;
    }
    if(e.which === 16 && isCtrl === true) {
        /* the code below will execute when CTRL + SHIFT are pressed */

        /* end of code */
        return false;
    }
};

document.getElementById('capture').onclick = function(){
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        tabId = tab.id;
        document.getElementById('page').innerText = tab.id;
    });
};
```

**I thought this would be the solution, but it didn't work:**

```
/* the code below will execute when CTRL + SHIFT are pressed */

chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
   chrome.tabs.reload(tabId);
});

/* end of code */
```

Having `var tabId = 0;` as a global variable seems pointless so I thought *message passing* should be the solution, but the problem with that is that I don't understand how I should implement it.

Any suggestions on how to refresh the tab from anywhere based on its ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `contentscript.js` is just a file with programmatic instructions written in JavaScript. Those instructions are interpreted as fresh and new each time they are loaded into a particular execution environment. Your popup and your content scripts are separate execution environments.

The `contentscript.js` file itself does not store state. When `contentscript.js` is loaded in a content script environment, the content script execution environment has no idea where else `contentscript.js` has been included.

The correct pattern to use here would be to have a [background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) maintain state and remember the tab ID of the last captured tab. The popup would use [message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to send the current tab ID to the background page (using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` in the popup and `chrome.runtime.onMessage` in the background page). Then, later, the content script would send a message to the background page when it saw a `Ctrl+Shift` press, and the background page would invoke `chrome.tabs.reload(tabId)`.

Inside **extension.html**, instead of your current `<script>` tag:

```
document.getElementById("capture").onclick = function() {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        tabId = tab.id;

        // send a request to the background page to store a new tabId
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:"new tabid", tabid:tabId});
    });
};
```

Inside **contentscript.js**:

```
/* the code below will execute when CTRL + SHIFT are pressed */

// signal to the background page that it's time to refresh
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:"refresh"});

/* end of code */
```

**background.js**:

```
// maintaining state in the background
var tabId = null;

// listening for new tabIds and refresh requests
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

        // if this is a store request, save the tabid
        if(request.type == "new tabid") {
            tabId = request.tabid;
        }

        // if this is a refresh request, refresh the tab if it has been set
        else if(request.type == "refresh" && tabId !== null) {
            chrome.tabs.reload(tabId);
        }
});
```

Comment: Inside extension.html inside <script> tag it is not allowed to have an inline script

Comment: I just pasted the inline script code into script.js and changed in the extension.html <script src="contentscript.js"></script> to <script src="script.js"></script>, which worked